# Perform an operation to each item of a list

Tags: python, list, operators

I have a list of numbers and i need to divide them all by a specific number.

Lets say i want to divide all of the items by 2

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
wanted_list = [1/2,2/2,3/2,4/2,5/2,6/2,7/2]
```

I attempted a for loop that changes each but it didnt work for some reason like it didnt do the operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
wanted_list = [i/2 for i in list]
print(wanted_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume san's answer is the best approach, as it utilizes lists comprehension and in that case a new list is created automatically, however considering what you wrote, you can as well use a for loop, only you need to store the result somewhere, ex:

```
data = [2, 4, 6]
wanted_data = []

for d in data: 
    wanted_data.append(int(d/2))

print(wanted_data)
```